# Nested JSON output

Tags: views, services

I have a Services View display in `Drupal 8` which gives the details about a particular article taking the node id as an argument.
The JSON output is a flat list of the results.

```
[
 {
  title: "This is a Remote Post in Drupal 8",
  field_author: "1",
  body: "Test Body",
  changed: "1441718833",
  field_rd_date: "1443009600",
  field_email: "foo@bar.com",
  field_link: "Drupal - Some post on WSDatahttps://www.drupal.org/node/2564277",
  field_number: "11053",
  field_phone: "+917760369147",
  status: "Yes",
  type: "Remote Content Type",
  field_content_ref: "152, 106, 109",
 }
]
```

I need to nest a few fields in the above result. For example, for `field_link: "Drupal - Some post on WSDatahttps://www.drupal.org/node/2564277"` I need to get the following.

```
field_link: [
 <strong>link_title</strong>: Drupal - Some post on WSData,
 <strong>link</strong>: https://www.drupal.org/node/2564277
]
```

field_content_ref should be given as the following.

```
{
 <strong>field_content_ref</strong>: [
  152,
  106,
  109
 ]
}
```

How can I achieve this using Views Services?

Comment: In Drupal 7 (via Views Datasource [Views JSON]), this wasn't possible (without a hook available via said contrib module), and I would typically just add 2 fields to the View, one for the link title and one for the link URL. As for D8, I do not know.